# How can i set a Google Maps Marker to the Center while resizing the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I wish you can help me to fix google map marker to the center while resizing the browser. I need responsive map, so...

Thanks for your time, i hope you can help me.

Here is the code:

-HTML:

```
<!-- Map container -->
<div id="map_container">

<!-- Map -->
<iframe id="map" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zshaN7gd-oek.kGuRBCX_l_sU"></iframe>
<!-- / Map -->

</div>
<!-- / Map container -->
```

-CSS:

```
#map_container {
margin: 200px auto;
padding: 0;
width: 90%;
height: 250px; }

#map_container #map {
position: relative;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen window resize event and then set center:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
       map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922));
 });
```

The above solution works for  [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) But if you are only using iframe method then things will not be well for you in terms of responsive design as well as I know..

Alright, here is the working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dhu1gvu/) and the example that I slightly modified from :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resize event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
            };
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922));
            });
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you write me a fiddle, i don't know how i rarely use stack overflow?

Comment: Let me try, need a few mins.

Comment: Meanwhile please take a loot at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: I found an extnded fiddle instead of creating on: click add marker and resize to see how it works.. http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

Comment: im sure it works, but i have iframe, that's the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: :) you're welcome. My answer gives you a responsive map as you asked for. Out of curiosity, Is it Google Maps Engine that makes you avoid google maps API v3? If So then you may need to look at : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers

Comment: @wooer: you are great man, Need to learn from  you many things. Fantastic work. Keep it UP.

Comment: @NadeemKhan : I want to thank you (although an upvote might have meant nearly the same:) ) This place is full of great people most of which are greater than me...

Comment: @wooer: Hehehehe, did that also.. :)

Comment: @wooer Just wanted to say thanks for putting the time into answering this so well also. Helped me a lot  :)

Comment: @ElwoodP You're most welcome and glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

following code will reload your map every time whenever window size is change so your map marker will be in center automatically because every time we are getting a new map which will set marker in to center.. 
hope this will help!

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var ref=$('iframe:first').attr('src');
   $('iframe:first').attr('src',ref);
});
```